# Connecting an application to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have Mongodb running in vsc via the terminal. I've downloaded mongoose. When I try to run the application nothing happens. I've tried localhost in the connection string, i've tried localhost:27017, I can't a response at all to know whether it's connected.  I also downloaded the npm `mongodb` package just in case.

```
var mongoose = require ("mongoose")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cat_app", {useNewUrlParser: true});

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({name: String , age: Number , temperment: String });

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

var george = new Cat ({
    name: "George",
    age: 11,
    temperment: "Grouchy"
});

george.save(function(err, cat) {if (err) {console.log("Something Went Wrong")}

else {console.log("We Just Saved A Cat To The DB"); console.log(cat)}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have refactored your code a bit for better readability and have tried it out on my machine. by running the command "node app.js" the code successfully inserted the entry in the database. Try the code below and if that doesn't work for you they may be something wrong with your mongo configuration.

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cat_app", {useNewUrlParser: true});

var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema (
    {
        name: String , 
        age: Number , 
        temperment: String 
    }
);

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

var george = new Cat ({
    name: "George",
    age: 11,
    temperment: "Grouchy"
});

george.save((err, cat) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Something Went Wrong");
        } else {
            console.log("We Just Saved A Cat To The DB"); 
            console.log(cat);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I wasn't saving the file before I ran it.  That solved everything.  Thanks for the help yall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until mongoose connected to the DB using either promises or callbacks:

```
var mongoose = require ("mongoose")


var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({name: String , age: Number , temperment: String });

var Cat = mongoose.model("Cat", catSchema);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cat_app", {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  var george = new Cat({
    name: "George",
    age: 11,
    temperment: "Grouchy"
  });

  george.save(function(err, cat) {
    if (err) {console.log("Something Went Wrong")}
    else {
      console.log("We Just Saved A Cat To The DB");
      console.log(cat);
    }
  })
});
```

It's also a good opportunity to check for any connection errors